# How to check radio button from group2 by checking the radio button in group1?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have two radiogroups. The example of codeis bellow:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="Radio1">Radio 1</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="Radio2">Radio 2</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="radio" id="Radio3">Radio 3</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="radio" id="Radio4">Radio 4</label>
</form>
```

What I wan't to do is that when I check Radio 1 the Radio 3 is also automaticly selected and when I select Radio 2, Radio 4 is selected. So if Radio 1 is selected Radio 1 and Radio 3 are checked and if Radio 2 is selected Radio 2 and Radio 4 are checked.

Comment: What if radio 2 and radio 4 are clicked? should radio 1 and radio 3 be checked?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a quick jQuery click handler for radio1 and radio2 to set the .checked property of radio3 and radio4 respectively.  Note that I use the [0] index on $("#radio3")[0].checked to reference the html element instead of the jQuery object.  Note also the use of this instead of $(this) to reference the currently clicked html element.

```
$("#radio1").click(function(){
    $("#radio3")[0].checked = this.checked
});

$("#radio2").click(function(){
    $("#radio4")[0].checked = this.checked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Radio1').on('change',function() {
    var val = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#Radio3').prop('checked',val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, to handle both radio buttons in one handler :

```
$('input[name=RadioGroup1]').click(function(){
    var i = parseInt(this.id.slice(-1), 10)+2;
    $('#Radio'+i).attr('checked', 'checked');
});​
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/yXxfn/)